# How to Escape Custom Meta Data And Prefix Custom Meta ID

Tags: customization

Here is a code snippet where I tried to retrieve a custom meta data from a custom post type.

```
$p_client_link = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'client_link', true );
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $p_client_link); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'client_logo' ); ?></a>
```

My queries are:

1. Q. esc_url( $p_client_link); ==  right/wrong? esc_url() or esc_attr()?
2. Q. custom meta id client_link. Is it necessary to add prefix with this custom meta id like ‘p_client_link’?
3. Q. Is it right to use esc_url() for any ‘href’ attribute value?

N. B. I have been developing a one page WordPress theme for themeforest submission.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. esc_url() - The correct option. He will prepare a string for use in attributes. Doc: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/
2. Adding a prefix is correct. You will secure your variables from overriding with other plug-ins.
3. yes

Comment: Thanks much @TrubinE :) . As for 2 no., actually I would like to know about the meta id which we use in the admin panel, not the variable I took. ( $post->ID, 'client_link', true). This is the id 'client_link'. Thanks again :)

Comment: I meant that id should be unique, the prefix to us in this helps